# IIS-7 wildcard redirect web.config with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iis, iis-7, web-config

Have a wordpress site running on IIS 7 shared server that is replacing an html site.  I have only experience with apache so....
Need to modify the web.config file for the following
Add wildcard redirect to redirect all old site  .htm pages to corresponding wordpress page.  so /about.htm would got to /about and /contact-us.htm would go to /contact-us

- Also need to add some specific redirects that will work within wordpress
  For example:
  http://sitename.com/articles redirects to http://sitename/news-and-events

Below is the default web.config file that was installed...and is working as far as general wordpress functionality.
I have tried some suggestions I found here that were related to removing .aspx but either they seem to have no effect or caused 500 error.  Also as I am not sure if I am placing the rules in the right place/order within the file hierarchy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress: http://sitename.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```